# how to import Asx3mer on flex?

Tags: apache-flex

Firstly i'm just a week old to flex.
I want to convert some data to XML format and then display.
I found I could use :

```
    var myContactXML:XML= Asx3mer.instance.toXML(myContact);
```

Here i need Asx3mer.as class. I'm not sure if it is a in-built class. CTRL+shift+O doesn't help either.
I tried copying the code of this class into a action-script but it has other dependencies as well.

Pls help

Thanks,Bhu

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the [library](http://code.google.com/p/asx3m/downloads/list) and add it to your `lib` folder.

Make sure to add it as well in your flex build path, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will help you import it (in Eclipse like IDEs)